# Ambiguous Reference when using gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I made a C# program which allows me to get information from an Oracle database. Now I succeeded in showing a row in my application. My next objective is to put the database information in a gridview which also allows you to click on it which activates a function. I was wondering how to do this. I read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx , but I still don't get how to do this.

At the beginning it says

```
Namespace:  System.Windows.Controls

Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)
```

Now I've found the reference `PresentationFramework` and I added it. After that I added

`using System.Windows.Controls`

When I added the reference I got an error:

```
Error   1   'UserControl' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' and 'System.Windows.Controls.UserControl'
```

at:

```
public partial class DockableWindow : UserControl
{
```

and

```
Error   2   'ArcMapAddin28.DockableWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Handle' and no extension method 'Handle' accepting a first argument of type 'ArcMapAddin28.DockableWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

at:

```
        protected override IntPtr OnCreateChild()
        {
            m_windowUI = new DockableWindow(this.Hook);
            return m_windowUI.Handle; //red line under the word Handle
        }
```

What is going wrong here?

and is this even the right way to get to my next objective?

Comment: Are you asking about WPF, Windows Forms, or what?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok thanks. Windows Forms btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were looking at the wrong control. You want a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

See "[DataGridView Control Overview (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k39d6s23.aspx)".

Comment: Can you add some more explaining as to why?

Comment: Why? Because you were looking at the WPF "GridView" control, not the Windows Forms "GridView" control.